# Ubuntu not switching open windows like MS Windows OS

Tags: 14.04, windows, downloads, lts

I am on Ubuntu 14.04. One thing I noticed bugging me really bad that I did not notice in previous releases is the automatic switching of open windows. For example, when I download a file the option comes up to save, well I am used to just pressing enter immediately or just typing the save as name of the file. Now I have to click on the window then press enter to save or start typing a new name for the file. Is there a way to have Ubuntu automatically switch windows like when I download a file?

Sorry to everyone if I didn't do a good job explaining my question. Wasn't sure what words to use to describe it. I also searched everywhere for an answer for several weeks however, it might be my poor way of describing the problem as well that I can't find an answer.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome

Comment: I don't have a save/open dialog... I only get that is firefox.

Comment: @Tim: By default, Chrome(ium) auto-saves to the Downloads folder, but this can be changed/deselected. However, for me, when downloading a file in Chromium, the save dialog comes up on top. It could also be that the window manager (KDE for me) is at play.

Comment: Indeed. I absolutely hate it when new windows take focus and try to disable it where I can. If OP's using compiz or mutter (Unity or Gnome Shell), autofocusing new windows should be the default.

Comment: It does come up on top for me as saiarcot895 described. @muru, I do have compiz installed. Is there something I should disable? Trailfocus is enabled...